# Removing a Cell if a special character exists?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

How can I remove a cell if a specific character exists?

I have a spreadsheet of email addresses that I need to remove non-user addresses from.  We have two types of standard addresses:

- user accounts (firstname.lastname@company.com)
- service accounts (servicename@company.com).

I was hoping to automate the removal of the service accounts from the list and make this process repeatable.

Comment: Do you want a VBA or non-VBA solution? What have you tried? Please show what code or formulae you've used to solve it and we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a temp column next to the email address. Then you can use a formula to determine the type of address. This formula assumes your email address in A1, and it determines if the email account name has a period in it.

```
=IF(FIND(".",A1)<FIND("@",A1),"User","Service")
```

Comment: Although I had to fiddle with it a bit (don't know why it wouldn't work straight out), but it works great.  Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

A quick VBA method:

```
Sub RemoveServiceAccounts(ByRef rng As Range)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*.*@*", Operator:=xlAnd
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

e.g.

```
Sub Test()
    RemoveServiceAccounts Selection
End Sub
```